# What ports does Management Studio use to connect to SQL Server (2005)

Tags: sql-server, load-balancing, ssms, port

I have SQL Server 2005 operating on a remotely hosted server and wish to access it from my own machine using management studio

The firewall on the remote server is allready setup to allow all traffic from my external IP - and that works great.

However I have a load balancing router that has a second line attached to it - unfortunatly the second line has a dynamic external IP.

I need to therefore set up a rule in the router to always send data from Management studio on the first line - but I need to know the port numbers.

Can you advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1433 and 1434. Due to how the slammer worm operated, you'll find that a lot of ISPs out there filter these ports.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968872

Answer (score 2):

You can also set SQL Server to listen on a specific port of your choosing.  Here's a good article on how to set it up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx